# Restricted Access for SIM when use internet (3G, 2G and wi-fi)

Tags: calls, internet, sim-card

I am using THL W3+ and i have some problems when I switch on the internet (3G,2G, wi-fi) - it is working in normal mode for not more than 5 minutes and then the SIM and voice calls are in restricted mode and PIN is required.

Did somebody meet such problem and did somebody find a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by restricted mode? Does the SIM lock? Drop out of the network?

Comment: it appears the "Enter PIN" screen, the same as you just switched the phone on. until you enter the PIN and it is successfully accepted, there is no voice call available (neither incoming, nor outgoing)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it's a problem with the SIM card. My suggestion would be to check the SIM card seating and verify that there's no dust or debris between the SIM card and the connectors. If this doesn't help, try to use another SIM to test if it's a problem with the SIM card itself. If the device works with the other SIM, take your SIM to the carrier and ask for a replacement. If not, then I'd suggest taking the phone back to the shop for warranty repair.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Because it has a common behavior when i use 3G/2G or Wi-Fi ... that is why I consider it should not be a problem of SIM card. To be sure ... i also checked that out and the problem remains even with another SIM card.